# Modifying Insert statements before PutHiveStreaming

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

My CSV file contains a column with DATE TIME format like 12-10-2017 11:30

Now using puthivestreaming i can insert those records easily but my requirement is to remove just the TIME from this & keep only 12-10-2017

I can acheive this using Hive command line with substr() method while inserting, Not sure if Nifi supports it

I also thought about ReplaceText but since i have multiple DateTIMe like columns on single row, i cannot do this.

How can i achieve this?.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily get your required column by using getDelimitedField.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield

Input-->`1,12-10-2017 11:30,23`

in replaceText,just give `${Input:getDelimitedField(2):substringBefore(' ')}`

It yields flow file content with `12-10-2017`.

Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: thanks. Can we use this processor after convertCSVtoAvro ?.

Comment: Why you are convert csvToAvro?

Comment: My current flow is inserting records into Hive using getFile -> convertCSVtoAVRO -> PutHiveStreaming. Is this fine?.

Comment: Looks like this is not working. It's returning an empty file. How to get Input attribute?.

Comment: In your current flow,given solutions not to be work.

Comment: What do you recommend ?. I need to put CSV into Hive table